# I sored my media file in my google drive. it's possible I can fetch my media files in Django?

Tags: django, web, backend

I want to store images or videos of my websites in Google Drive and fetch them in Django . please give me instructions on how can do this procedure. I'm doing this because I want to Speed up my websites.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please fix the spelling in your question (it's `MEDIA_ROOT`, not what you wrote). Please also don't use all caps in the question title.

Comment: You also need to elaborate more. OK, you can store them in another drive/server and tell Django `MEDIA_ROOT = "your other drive or remotely mounted directory for the other server"`. What exactly is the problem?